# AdMob - Use one AdUnitID or multiple ones?

Tags: javascript, react-native, admob

This question relies more on theory then code, it is about the AdMob `AdBanner` but also just ads in general which you can implement in a react-native app.

If you are familiar with AdMob, you know you can create multiple `AdBanner` or also `RewardAds` and place them in your code but here is the question:

Should I create one `AdBanner` and place it on multiple screens inside my App or should I create different `adUnits` and for each screen implement another `AdUnit`?

From my perspective, I do not see any difference beside that with seperate `adUnits` you have a better overview on which screen has the most activity and which screen makes more profit but that is all. It seems to me much more easy and gives me a better overview if I only use one `adUnitID` for Banners, one `adUnitID` for `RewardAds` etc.

What is your opinion on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating ad unit for each screen, I've notice that when I use one Unit ID all the banners will show the same ad until it get refreshed everywhere, but if I use separate unit ID for each banner the ads will be different which will result in better revenue.